# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, build, server-side-rendering

I have done project build using command `ng build --prod`. It generate successfully build but this build not able to run on live server, It gives following error:-

```
main.0769518151819531d924.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at v (main.0769518151819531d924.js:1)
    at Mf (main.0769518151819531d924.js:1)
    at t.get (main.0769518151819531d924.js:1)
    at kt (main.0769518151819531d924.js:1)
    at Pt (main.0769518151819531d924.js:1)
    at Et (main.0769518151819531d924.js:1)
    at main.0769518151819531d924.js:1
    at main.0769518151819531d924.js:1
    at Df (main.0769518151819531d924.js:1)
    at Mf (main.0769518151819531d924.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.7d30aceca8fe7a5b6974.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.7d30aceca8fe7a5b6974.js:1)
    at polyfills.7d30aceca8fe7a5b6974.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.7d30aceca8fe7a5b6974.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.0769518151819531d924.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.7d30aceca8fe7a5b6974.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.7d30aceca8fe7a5b6974.js:1)
    at g (polyfills.7d30aceca8fe7a5b6974.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.7d30aceca8fe7a5b6974.js:1)
    at m (polyfills.7d30aceca8fe7a5b6974.js:1)
```

[image]

Comment: Try initializing the object with `{}` on which `hasOwnProperty` is applied

Comment: Thanks for answer but how do i find that particular object which have  hasOwnProperty at the this stage, i have build my complete project and it successfully build, but after deploying the build folder, it gives above error.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I cannot suggest. But seems to be the only way to go, just cross check all your objects which are using that method. That should not take very long time.

Comment: Sure, I'll cross check all the objects, and let you know the status. thank you.

Comment: @Amit Chigadani, I have tried to all my object with { } but still no change, their is same  problem.

Comment: @VaibhavGaikwad Amit is right. Your object which is used in the page is undefined. So, that's why it cannot access `hasOwnProperty`. Wherever you use `hasOwnProperty()` function, first you should check whether that object exists or not (i.e. it is initialized or not).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the line of code or the object type used here
But, generally if you received this error - then you probably required to check your variables before using them.

In Angular7 you probably use TypeScript (?) and by that - you're using something like `export class ..` and in that case `hasOwnProperty` doesn't exists ( on `interface / type` - you do have.

In typescript you have all kinds of options to first check if you have a value before you use it.... for example:

```
console.log(user.department?.length);
console.log(user.department !== undefined);
console.log(user.address?.country !== undefined));
console.log(user.address?.country?.toLowerCase());
console.log('department' in user);
```

etc .. etc..